# Where all.js in new MeanJS?

Tags: meanjs

I am learning MeanJS right now, watching a lot of video courses, but EVERYONE uses old version of MeanJS where is tottally different folder and files structure, that I have. It is very uncomfortable for noob like me.

Right now I am stuck at moment how to use custom css files.In every freaking video teachers modify all.js file. BUT I CAN'T FIND IT IN MY MEAN JS VERSION. I guess, they renamed it or something. Help me please. I just don't want to loose my sleep with this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `all.js`, in the latest MEAN.JS version you can configure the assets to be used in the app in different stages (development, production, testing, etc). You just have to go to `config/assets/` and edit the right file for your situation, probably `default.js` might be the one you're looking for. In that file you can add custom css files to be loaded into the app.